# SQLite Insert Into command causing a crash. (C#)

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm somewhat new to C#, and completely new to SQLite. SQLite is probably way overkill for this project but I wanted to learn it so I'm using it anyway. I'm making a discord bot. The problem is that whenever I do my only command it terminates. I've managed to find the source of the problem and its a command in SQLite to insert data into a row.

```
m_dbConnection.Open();
string sql = $"INSERT INTO `Cases` ( plaintiffid, accusedid, channelid ) values ( {plaintiff.Id.ToString()}, {accused.Id.ToString()}, {caseChannel.Id.ToString()} )";
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
m_dbConnection.Close();
```

Everytime I start the program it also runs this:

```
public static SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection { get; private set; }
public static string CasePath { get; } = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + @"/DiscourtBot/Cases.sqlite";
public static void Start()
{
    if (!File.Exists("Cases.sqlite"))
    {
        SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("Cases.sqlite");
        m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=Cases.sqlite;Version=3;");
        m_dbConnection.Open();
        string sql = "CREATE TABLE `Cases` ( plaintiffid INTEGER, accusedid INTEGER, channelid INTEGER UNIQUE )";
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        m_dbConnection.Close();
    }
    else m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=Cases.sqlite;Version=3;");
}
```

No exceptions are thrown.

I've tested a bit of the code in another program and this code also causes it to terminate.

```
SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("Cases.sqlite");
m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=Cases.sqlite;Version=3;");
m_dbConnection.Open();
string sql = "CREATE TABLE `Cases` ( plaintiffid BIGINT, accusedid BIGINT, channelid BIGINT )";
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
m_dbConnection.Close();

m_dbConnection.Open();
string sqll = $"INSERT INTO `Cases` ( plaintiffid, accusedid, channelid ) values ( 5, 5, 5 )";
SQLiteCommand commandd = new SQLiteCommand(sqll, m_dbConnection);
commandd.ExecuteNonQuery();
m_dbConnection.Close();
```

Discord ID's usually look something like this: 394343217715216384
I'd appreciate it if anyone could help me.

Comment: and what exception you get?

Comment: "it crashes" is not a good problem description. Did you get an error/exception? What's the message?

Comment: terminates would be a better way to describe it. What datatype could handle that number?

Comment: I have tested your code and there is no error. Did you check if the record has been inserted?

Comment: Thats not the correct way to create SQL.  Especially with SQLite you want to use SQL PArameters.  Note that you define the table with INTEGER, then pass `foo.bar.Id.ToString()`

Comment: Im now getting this error message:
The program '[89704] dotnet.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.

Comment: Just a warning, if you end up trying to include user input in something like the first example code block you'll probably end up vulnerable to SQL injection, take a look at how SQL injection works. Right now your example is fine because you pass it discord ids and those can't really contain an injection attack.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of messing around I found out that an API I was using was interfering with a constructor. I solved the problem by putting the INSERT INTO code in the same place where I called the constructor.

I'm still not completely sure what was going on but it's fixed now.